# show user based on user_meta

Tags: post-meta, user-meta, users

it's possible to show user if my logic like this it's better to give illustration

USER

```
I have two users with usermeta:
user A have usermeta country with value "USA" and univ with value "UCLA"
user B ONLY have usermeta country with value "USA"
```

POST

```
I also have two posts:
post 1 contain postmeta country with value "USA" 
post 2 ONLY have postmeta country with value "USA" and state with value "TX"
```

LOGIC

```
IF post have postmeta "COUNTRY" => "USA":
ECHO user A & user B
IF post have postmeta "COUNTRY" => "USA" AND have postmeta "UNIV" => "UCLA"
ONLY ECHO user A
```

so in post 1 show all user A & b but in post 2 only show user A because user A have state.

My code so far

```
get_users(array(
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
        array(
            'key' => 'verifier_assign_country',
            'value' => $countryCode,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'verifier_assign_univ',
                'value' => $univCode,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    )
), 'objects');
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

you can create conditionnal arguments like that :

```
$user_args = [
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'verifier_assign_country',
            'value' => $countryCode,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    )
];

if ("" !== $univCode) {

    $user_args["meta_query"][] = array(
        'key' => 'verifier_assign_univ',
        'value' => $univCode,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );

}

$users = get_users($user_args);
```